# Import a file with constants in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

Is it possible to import a file with a bunch of constants in another twig file?

Such as :

```
{% set VAR1 = constant("...:var1") %}
{% set VAR2 = constant("...:var2") %}
{% set VAR3 = constant("...:var3") %} 
...
```

And then, in another file use those constants?

I have tried `include`, `import`, `use` and `embed`. 
None of these seem to fit the situation.

Comment: Basically no.  You can put your constants in a base twig file and then extend from it.  Your constants will flow down.  However, when you include(aka import) a twig file the constants won't flow up.  You will need a different strategy.

Comment: @putvande Of course I tried some things. I thought about defining them in the base template, but how do you handle 100+ constants?

Comment: You could make a twig extension function get_constant('name') but basically you really should reconsider your design.  By the way, you can look under app/cache/dev/twig to see the various generated php twig files.  It's hard to follow at first but once you see what is happening then it becomes clear that each imported file lives in it's own context and does not impact it's parent context.

Answer (score 1):

By design, you can't import variables from another context, as `{% include %}` without parameter will pass your current context by copy, not by reference.

This is the exact same thing for `{% macro %}` with the `_context` variable as parameter, so you cannot create new variables in the context from inside a macro and then `{% import %}` your macro file anywhere.

But, you can create variables from an extended file, and use them in the child file.

For example:

<kbd>a.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% set test = 'Hello!' %}
```

<kbd>b.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% extends 'a.html.twig' %}
{{ test }}
```

Will display "Hello!" when rendering b.html.twig, or any other files that extends a.html.twig.

If, by design, you can't extends a parent template in your application, you can create a Twig extension and implement the `getGlobals()` method [(doc)](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id1).

Example (for me in Fuz/TestBundle, replace all namespaces to fit your needs):

The Twig extension :

<kbd>PHP</kbd> Fuz/TestBundle/Twig/Extension/AppGlobalsExtension.php

```
<?php

namespace Fuz\TestBundle\Twig\Extension;

class AppGlobalsExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getGlobals()
    {
        return array(
            'var1' => \Fuz\TestBundle\Component\Service::SOME_CONSTANT_A,
            'var2' => \Fuz\TestBundle\Component\Service::SOME_CONSTANT_B,
            'var3' => \Fuz\TestBundle\Component\Service::SOME_CONSTANT_C,
            // ...
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appglobals';
    }

}
```

The configuration :

<kbd>YML</kbd> Fuz/TestBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
parameters:
    fuz_tools.twig.appglobals_extension.class: Fuz\TestBundle\Twig\Extension\AppGlobalsExtension

services:
    fuz_tools.twig.appglobals:
        class: '%fuz_tools.twig.appglobals_extension.class%'
        tags:
          - { name: twig.extension }
```

You can now use `{{ var1 }}`, `{{ var2 }}` ... anywhere in your application views.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick for you (with `with`), just pass variables:

`{% include "ACMETestBundle::test.html.twig" with {var1: VAR1, var2: VAR2, ... } %}`

Comment: OP wants to include a file initializing those variables to use them in his current context, not to pass some variables of the current context to the included file.